# How do I make the line break after the span tag closes?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve something of the following kind of UI
[image: Screenshot with frameworks and perfect line breaks]

I have tried the following

```css
p {
  max-width: 30ch;
}

p span {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <em>
        Frameworks used:
    </em>

  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>hello world</span>
</p>
```

but I end up with something looking like
[image: picture of my html code returning erroneous results]

Is there any way with pure CSS (or with JS if the prior not possible) to achieve a line break only *after* the `span` tag closes?

Comment: span {display: inline-block;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if `display:inline-block` can be a quick solution along with some margin bottom from your current setup.

```
 display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:0.5rem;
```

https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/GRwVdwm

**CSS Updated:**

```
p {
    max-width: 30ch;
}

p span {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:0.5rem;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0.875rem; 
    line-height: 1.25rem;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 999px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `p span` rule.
Also, since `p span` is a too common general selector, I suggest you add a class to those SPANs and use that class in CSS like i.e:

```css
.pill {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* ...other styles */
}
```

or on the parent element: `.pills span {`.
For the parent element I'd also suggest using CSS `flex` like:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  font: 16px/1.4 sans-serif;
  background: #ea526f;
}

.pills {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pills span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0.875rem; 
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="pills">
  <b>Technologies:</b><span>C</span><span>C++</span><span>C#</span><span>Java</span><span>Python</span><span>SQL</span><span>Typescript</span><span>xCode</span><span>Javascript</span><span>Unity 3D Engine</span><span>Elixir</span><span>Erlang</span><span>Prolog</span><span>MIPS Assembly HTML</span><span>Clojure</span><span>CSS</span><span>Jira</span><span>React</span><span>Vue</span><span>Ruby on Rails</span><span>NextJS</span><span>Visual Studio Code</span><span>Git</span><span>React Native</span><span>Visual Studio</span><span>MVP</span><span>MVVM</span><span>MySQL</span><span>Node.js</span><span>IJX</span><span>Design</span><span>Continous Integration</span><span>CMake</span><span>BigQuery</span><span>Kibana</span><span>Framer Motion</span><span>Ul Design</span><span>MariaDB</span><span>Flask</span><span>Github Actions</span><span>Kotlin</span><span>IntelliJ</span><span>Rider</span><span>CLion</span>
</div>
```